# getBindingContext() getProperty of undefined

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I've got a problem to get the binding context of the `listItem`

Here is my data model:

```
{
  "Items": [
        {
            "ItemTypeID": "0",
            "Name": "A"
        },
        {
            "ItemTypeID": "1",
            "Name": "B"
        },
        {
            "ItemTypeID": "2",
            "Name": "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

My view:

```
<List id="idItemTypes" mode="SingleSelectMaster" select="handleListSelect"
            items="{itemTypes>/ItemTypes}">
            <items>
                <StandardListItem title="{itemTypes>Name}" type="Navigation" />             
            </items>
        </List>
```

My view works fine and is showing me all Items from my model. But if i select an item from my list i can't get the binding context. It's undefined all the time.

My controller:

```
handleListSelect : function(oEvent) {
    this._showDetail(oEvent.getParameter("listItem"));
},
_showDetail : function(oItem) {
    this.getRouter().navTo("Items", {
        console.log( oItem.getBindingContext() ); //undefined
        ItemTypeID : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("ItemTypeID")
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the binding context of clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556515/how-to-get-the-binding-context-of-clicked-item)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common mistake: If you use named models, don't forget to specify the model name as argument for the `getBindingContext` method :-)

```
this.getRouter().navTo("Items", {
    console.log( oItem.getBindingContext("itemTypes") ); //should now hold an object
    ItemTypeID : oItem.getBindingContext("itemTypes").getProperty("ItemTypeID")
});
```